# "Просто если" — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

*Просто(,) если в других условиях кофе жарить и в другой посуде, всё может измениться.*

Вопрос насчёт запятой. Часто не ставлю подобные запятые, относя *просто* к придаточной части, но всё-таки, подумав, решил, что логически *просто* скорее относится не к условию, а к основной части (в данном случае к изменению). А вы как думаете?

Конечно, если поставить *то* перед основной частью, первая запятая не будет нужна, но вопрос именно о случае без второй части союза.

Comment: *Конечно, если поставить то перед основной частью, первая запятая не будет нужна* — чего это? Правило о стыке союзов.

Comment: @oleedd: не понял твоего монолога))

Comment: По какому правилу запятая не будет нужна? В правилах о "то" не сказано о частицах.

Comment: О, спасибо, oleedd! Действительно, в правилах такого нету, но я заметил, что когда "то" есть, то не ставят никогда в этом случае. Ну и то, что изъять невозможно придаточное без потери смысла, тоже в пользу этого говорит.

Comment: На "просто" можно сделать ударение, тогда лучше поставить. Меня уже давно волнует этот вопрос. Особенно то, что делать, если наречие перед союзом. О частицах уже спрашивали пару раз.

Comment: А почему нельзя изъять придаточное? *Просто всё может измениться*. Или переставить в конец. Вы же говорите, что *просто* скорее относится к главному предложению.

Comment: Рад, что тоже интересует, oleedd! @АлександрСтрелец: так можно, конечно. А я-то говорил про случай, когда *то* есть!

Answer (score 4):

Запятая в данном случае не ставится, "просто" здесь усилительная частица.
См. [знаки препинания в СПП](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827520.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B10%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%C2%A7336).

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Подожду ещё ответов.

Comment: Указанные в правиле усилительные частицы относятся непосредственно к придаточному, а здесь нет: *Всё может измениться, просто если в других условиях кофе жарить и в другой посуде.*

Comment: В данном случае просто тоже усилительная частица. Запятая не требуется.

Comment: *то запятая ставится перед ними вопреки интонации (при чтении пауза перед ними не делается)* — там о случаях, когда придаточное после главного и когда частица относится непосредственно к придаточному. Говорится об отсутствии паузы после главного предложения, после которого стоит частица.

Comment: А какая разница придаточное стоит после главного или перед ним?

Comment: В тех примерах частица относится непосредственно к придаточному. Другого быть не может, если придаточное после главного. Вам надо знать, что Розенталь формулировал правила по примерам, а не выдумывал, если в примерах нет такого, то это правило не о том. У Розенталя указано, что принцип заключается в том, что придаточное не отделяется от слова, посредством которого присоединяется. А в данном случае частица не присоединяет придаточное и не относится к нему.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил запятую:

```
Просто, если в других условиях кофе жарить и в другой посуде, всё может измениться.
```

Считаю, что "просто" здесь используется в качестве союза: соединяет предл. или чл. предл.). Выражает противопоставление, сопоставление (часто с уступительным оттенком).
Для меня это просто синонимично "однако", поэтому нужно вспомнить правила постановки запятой на стыке союзов.

---

Поскольку здесь нет второй части двойного союза [то], запятую следует поставить.

---

P.S. Большинство примеров из НКРЯ говорит о том, что нужна запятая (можно и дополнить предложение второй частью двойного союза [если...то], чтобы точно не ошибиться).

Comment: Большинство примеров с запятой из Нац.корпуса о которых вы говорите, имеют другое значение.  В них "просто" не усительная частица, а наречие. Но в Нац.корпусе есть и примеры с усилительной частицей просто — без запятой. Изучите контекст!

Comment: Чтобы вы понимали, был изучен конкретный случай - "Просто (,) если". В каком месте тут наречие: "Сакральный вопрос от Майи Студзинской // Litera_Dnepr, 2012.
"Просто, если ты настоящий писатель, все остальное ты будешь делать...".                           
 Форум: Петербургский школьник из Бостона: «Эти русские -– все на одно лицо» (2012).                                           
"Просто, если помните, тут недавно были статьи".

Comment: @Серж https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CoQCEuEBCt4BEnEKCQoDbGV4EgIKAAoWCgRmb3JtEg4KDNC%2F0YDQvtGB0YLQvgoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14Ch0KBWZsYWdzEhQKEihiY29tbWEpICYgKGZpcnN0KRJpCgkKA2xleBICCgAKEgoEZm9ybRIKCgjQtdGB0LvQuAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKAAoMCgRkaXN0IgQIARABIhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAohsn2z4TrmwhABSoCCAEyAQEwAQ%3D%3D